# Array type required in Delphi

Tags: delphi, vector

I rebuild the old project on Delphi, in the properties the position of the object is passed as a vector, and then it is written to the corresponding PosX properties, and so on, this is where the incomprehensible error "Array type required" occurs. I did not find such errors on the Internet.
What type is required, where is it required?

```
private
     { Private Properties }
     FPosition  : TVector;
     FDirection, FUp : TVector;
public
     property Position : TVector read FPosition write FPosition;
     property PosX : Single read FPosition[0]  write FPosition[0];
     property PosY : Single read FPosition[1] write FPosition[1];
     property PosZ : Single read FPosition[2] write FPosition[2];
```

The error is attached to the "]" character of each element of the vector

UPD:

Version Delphi 10.4.
I have 2 errors on each line starting with "property PosX" for a total of 6 errors
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOV8L.png)

I found how the type is declared:

```
TVector = record
  case Integer of
    0: (V: array[0..3]} of Single);
    1: (X,Y,Z,W : Single);
end;
```

Comment: Can you show how `TVector` declared? Could perhaps be related: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/E2016_Array_type_required_(Delphi)

Comment: TVector is owned by GLScene. TVector = array[0..3] of single;
But if I replace the FPosition type with "array [0..3] of single", then i have mismatch with type Position

Comment: I'm afraid that the solution is not so simple, because the program of 2005, and the GLScene engine itself, has changed a little, and besides, it is not so popular. For understanding, I found how the type is declared.

Comment: You may want to read about index specifiers in https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Properties_(Delphi)

Comment: Don't know what's up with your search engine but mine gave me this as the first hit on my search https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2016_Array_type_required_(Delphi)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by replacing FPosition [0] with FPosition.X

```
     property Position : TVector read FPosition write FPosition;
     property PosX : Single read FPosition.X write FPosition.X;
     property PosY : Single read FPosition.Y write FPosition.Y;
     property PosZ : Single read FPosition.Z write FPosition.Z;
```